Luca Serianni (1947-2022)
Sometimes meta can be used to spread news that might be interesting for the community. Unfortunately today a sad one reached the Italian newspapers.
Yesterday, July 21st 2022, the famous Italian linguist Luca Serianni died. He was in the hospital following a traffic accident.
He was one of the foremost Italian linguists. He's probably most known to the users of this site for his Italian grammar book, considered the most authoritative reference work on the subject and a frequent presence in many answers. He was also, together with Maurizio Trifone, one of the current editors of the famous Devoto-Oli dictionary, a constant companion of my school years.

(Scrivo in italiano perché comunque sono in italiano i testi a cui farò riferimento.)
Può essere un'idea raccogliere risorse interessanti (non lanci d'agenzia tutti simili tra loro) di e su Serianni. Comincio con le prime che ho in mente, ma questo commento è “Community wiki” e può essere ampliato e modificato liberamente.

“Scrivere bene significa leggere bene” di Luca Serianni (L'Indice)

Luca Serianni: «Chi ha scelto di fare l’insegnante non può prendersi il lusso di essere pessimista» (Treccani)

“Luca Serianni, lezioni di italiano” di Francesco Erbani (L'Essenziale / Internazionale)

Luca Serianni: "Il cibo nella Divina Commedia" in Cuadernos de Filologia Italiana, 14, 61-67 (2007)

Luca Serianni: "Dal testo di grammatica alla grammatica in atto" (2011)

Raccolta di filmati di lezioni e interventi di Serianni presso il sito della RAI

Luca Serianni: Un treno di sintomi. I medici e le parole: percorsi linguistici nel passato e nel presente, Garzanti libri (2005)


